# Is an azure account mandatory to use the azure kinect at all?

Tags: azurekinect

Do I need to sign up for an Azure account (even the free one) if I want to use the very basic body tracking functions of the Azure Kinect? From my understanding those should be possible to use offline with just the Kinect SDK...

Or is the account really just needed in case you want to use speech recognition and other AI services that use the Azure cloud services?

I couldn't find any definitive answer on the Kinect page or in the documentation. They only advise you "should" start off with creating an Azure account.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an account, just follow instructions: download SDK, connect the camera  and have at least a NVIDIA GTX 1050 running on your PC. You could plug it to older NVIDIA cards but the FPS will be very, very slow.